# How to use a custom object as a key in a map in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use TypeScript and I created a map using `new Map<KEY, TYPE>` where `KEY` is either a string, float or number.

In one special case I would like to use a custom class as a key to preserve some data structures:

```js
class Foo {
   name: string;
   data1: any;
   data2: any;
};

const map = new Map<Foo, ...>();

map.set(fooObject1, someData);
map.set(fooObject2, someData);
map.set(fooObject3, someData);

map.get('nameOfFooObject');
```

I would like to use `name` as the key identifier, but as said I would need to preserve `data1` and `data2` as well. Is there a way to set a primitive type as a key with a function to point to the key?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, are u trying to set your map like this? 
`map.set({name: 'test', data1: 'test1', data2: 'test2'}, 'some value')`

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the code-block. I hope that clarifies my intent

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having that custom object for key (which if you think about how map works you'll see is a bad idea), create a custom object for the value and add all properties that you want to preserve there.

Comment: Ok, seems to be the default approach then. Thanks for the clarification